# Dictionary Using Hash Of Object

Tags: c#

My program allows the server to send a module to a client, and the client will a respond back with module information after it has loaded it. The server store stores the client information in a List called 'loadingModules'. When the server receives that response from the client, it will remove the information from said list to indicate the load operation has completed for that module.

The problem here is is the way I'm currently doing it is by looping through the entire list and checking if two members are equal (ModuleName, and TimeStamp). This is not only just inefficient, but also makes the code look terrible. **I am wondering if there is some way to do it using a hash of those two members to access the modules in perhaps a dictionary instead of what I am currently doing**.

```
public List<ClientModule> LoadingClientModules = new();
public List<ClientModule> LoadedClientModules = new();

private void ClientModuleAdded_Callback(Packet packet)
{
    ClientModule f = Utils.ByteArrayToStructure<ClientModule>(packet.Payload, 0);
    Utils.Log.Information($"{_ClientInformation.ComputerUser} Loaded  {f.ModuleName} TimeDateStamp: {f.TimeDateStamp} Address: {f.Address}");
    LoadedClientModules.Add(f);

    LoadingClientModules.RemoveAll(i => i.ModuleName == f.ModuleName && i.TimeDateStamp == f.TimeDateStamp);

    OnClientModuleLoaded?.Invoke(this, f);
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. Create a string from a relevant ToString() overload of the two types and use a Dictionary<string,Module>. If you will only have one of each module in it, you could instead just use the module name as the key and then compare the date if you get an object back.

Comment: The one-liner looks terrible? I dont get the point. Is `LoadingClientModules` really so huge that it's inefficient? Is there only one with ModuleName  and TimeDateStamp or do you expect duplicates?

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is just a single tiny example from many in the project. There are many other parts through my project now where this is required where I now have to do several loops due to this. So in my opinion, I would say it makes the code hard to read. There can be multiple ones with the same name, but they can be different versions. (There will never be two with the same name and same version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide a custom `IEqualityComparter<ClientModule>` that compares these 2 properties. Then you can use that for a `Dictionary` or - better here - a `HashSet<ClientModule>`:

```
public HashSet<ClientModule> LoadingClientModules = new(new ClientModuleComparer());
public HashSet<ClientModule> LoadedClientModules = new(new ClientModuleComparer());

private void ClientModuleAdded_Callback(Packet packet)
{
    ClientModule f = Utils.ByteArrayToStructure<ClientModule>(packet.Payload, 0);
    LoadedClientModules.Add(f);
    LoadingClientModules.Remove(f);
}
```

Here's a possible implementation:

```
public class ClientModuleComparer : IEqualityComparer<ClientModule>
{
    public bool Equals(ClientModule? x, ClientModule? y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.ModuleName == y.ModuleName && y.TimeDateStamp == y.TimeDateStamp;
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] ClientModule obj)
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.ModuleName.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.TimeDateStamp.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this does not allow duplicates anymore. So you will not have multiple with the same ModuleName and TimeDateStamp in these collections. `Add` returns `false` in case of a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to explain the custom GetHashCode function? Particularly, just the calculations you're making.

Comment: @MemeMachine: that's just a copy&paste from the best practise answere here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-overriding-gethashcode

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary to store and find the data is always faster than implementing a list and searching through the list item but it costs more memory.

You may use a Tuple created from `ModuleName` and `TimeDateStamp` and use it as the key to define a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<(string,DateTime),ClientModule> LoadingModulesDictionary = new ...;
```

then use the dictionary as:

```
private void ClientModuleAdded_Callback(Packet packet)
{
    ClientModule f = Utils.ByteArrayToStructure<ClientModule>(packet.Payload, 0);
    LoadedClientModules.Add(f);
    LoadingModulesDictionary.Remove((f.ModuleName,f.DataTimeStam));
}
```

or define a unique id for each `ClientModule` object is to add a `Guid` field to the class and use the `guid` as the key for dictionary alternatively.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would you say there is a preferable choice between your answer and the other I had selected?

Comment: There is no preference in my view.